# GCP Load balaner - Fail over internet backend services

Tags: gcp-load-balancer, google-cloud-url-maps

We have below isolated services deployed on different cloud providers. Each service URL a specific to the cloud provider.

Service A - `https://service-a.region.cloudfunctions.net`.
Service B - `https://service-b.lambda-url.region.on.aws`
Service C - `https://service-c.azurewebsites.net/api/functionname`

We have configured all 3 services as internet backends in GCP under a single load balancer. How to configure a failover service B for service A in the GCP load balancer ? When both A and B are failed, we need to switch over to service C ?